# Dashboard for new users

Tags: dashboard, gamification, onboarding

I would like to ask what is the best solution for onboarding users dashboard.

Scenario A

1. when user login i will show them a big image to tell them that must add subscribers.
2. when they add 2 subscribers show the sidebar column with the list with subscribers.
3. and replace the image with the next task.

Scenario B

  when user login i will show them a big image to tell them that must add subscribers and lock the sidebar widgets (ex. list of subscribers)

Scenario C

  when user login i will show a popup for the next task.

Scenario D

  Show all my dashboard and at the top of sidebar a small box with next task

Task:

1. Add new subscribers
2. Add new event
3. Send new sms campaign.
4. Send new email campaign.

The application is for event scheduler, email and sms newsletters

Comment: Please tell us what is the app about?

Comment: Maybe also look at some of the questions relating to 'Blank State' design, one of which relates to dashboards: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86710/is-there-a-difference-between-a-blank-state-as-a-new-user-and-an-existing-user-w

Answer (score 1):

When I interact with an app I want to feel that I am in control.  I would go with Option D simply because locking out functionality makes an app feel "over guided". I would change the small box at the top with the next task to a noticeable top-of-page banner displaying the next required task to complete the current action.

Answer (score 0):

since there is business logic between the tasks (#1 happens before #2, #3 and #4 cannot start before #2 is completed), and people expect this logic (they know why they use your solution), I'd go with "D", so that people feel that they're making progress in a wizard